My coreDNS has a large number of plugin errors, and corends requests DNS timeout in/etc/resolv.conf
coredns：
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 NS: read udp 10.234.22.71:36985->169.254.25.10:53: i/o timeout
NodelocalDNS also has a large number of error [ERROR] plugins/errors: 2 redis.test.svc.cluster.local A: dial tcp 10.233.0.3:53: connect: connection refused
10.233.0.3 is my coreDNS address
I hope to resolve the related errors
